# Streaming to Facebook live API stopped working?

Tags: java, android, facebook, rtmp, live-streaming

I have been using this library to stream video to Facebook live though RTMP.

Since January 20th approximately Facebook has made some changes to their API that have broken my app. The only change I can see so far is they went from rtmp-api.facebook.com to live-api.facebook.com.

I am unable to find any Info about what changed and how to fix.

Does anybody here have a live streaming app or more experience with these streams?
Is there anything I need to do to be compliant with their new server? As far as I can see from the docs only the url has changed.

I also don't know what tool to use to debug this issue. The Android profiler is not catching the connection call and the issue happens before I send Facebook the stream path. So the initial rtmp connection is returning a header = -1 for some reason.

Link to library I'm using: https://github.com/octiplex/Android-RTMP-Muxer

Any tips on where to look are welcome.

Comment: I usually debug this with Wireshark, or some other packet capture software.  From there, you can dig through the packet dump for clues.  (Feel free to post a link to the packet capture on your question, and I'll take a look.)  By the way, is the URL you're using `rtmp://` or `rtmps://`?  Could that have been the change?

Comment: I'll try to debug this on wireshark, I did try both secure and regular stream. Will update question as soon as I get home.